# A little confusion on galois groups

Tags: galois-theory

We know $Gal(Q(\zeta_n)/Q) \cong (Z/nZ)^*$  for $n\geq 2$.
Then $Gal(Q(\zeta_2)/Q) \cong (Z/2Z)^*$ this means $Gal(Q(\zeta_2)/Q)$ has one element, the identity automorphism.
The map $\delta:Gal(Q(\zeta_2)/Q)\rightarrow Gal(Q(\zeta_2)/Q)$
where $\delta(a_0 + a_1\zeta^1)=a_0 - a_1\zeta^1$ is an automorphism that fixes Q by applying the property of ring homomorphisms.
**QUESTION:**
Whys is it that $\delta$ is not an element of $Gal(Q(\zeta_2)/Q)$?

Comment: Title: you have a little confusion already before Galois groups, namely about $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_2)/\mathbb{Q}$, which is the trivial $1$-degree field extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What *is* $\Bbb Q(\zeta_2)$? What is your $\zeta$? Write it out explicitly, and you will probably see your error.

Comment: im trying to check for errors but i cant really point out. can you please show your solution sir?

Comment: Can you answer my question, then? Which number is $\zeta$?

Comment: alright thanks i solved it. $Q(\zeta_2) = Q$

Comment: because the square roots of unity are 1 and -1

Comment: @unknownMe Which makes the Galois group trivial, as your theory told you it should be.